# Is "specificity" the correct noun for the state or the possibility of being specified?

Tags: programming, abstract-nouns

The motivation of this question is the following: there are entities in a computer program which can either be explicitly specified, or else they can be "inferred", that is, deduced automatically from other parts of the program without the programmer having to write them down. I need a noun to express that.

Is "specificity" the right noun for the state or the possibility of being specified? The online dictionaries I have consulted seem to give a slightly different meaning: being clear or exact, being narrowly circumscribed instead of general. But that's not quite the meaning I need to convey.

I guess "specifiedness" would be the correct word, but it doesn't seem to exist in dictionaries. "specifiability" does exist, but puts too much emphasis on the *potential* of being specified, while I want to talk about the *current* specified or inferred status of the entities in my program. Like: "what's the specifiedness of entities X and Y? —X is specified, while Y is inferred."

Comment: As you say, *specificity* means something like "specificness" -- a measure of how specific something is, not whether it's specified or not.

Comment: Yes@Andrew Leach; it is not about 'specified', but being 'specific'.

Comment: Wy not ask, “Are X and Y specified?” “X is specifiied. Y is left unspecified.”  Or “Are there specifications for X and Y?” ...

Comment: Maybe . . . What's the specification status of entities X and Y?  X is specified (specified = true); Y is inferred (specified = false).

Answer (score -2):

"Specificity" is used more in science than in general language.

I did have a professor in college who would write on my papers "use greater specificity" if I over-generalized in the paper.

But I rarely hear "specificity" in general conversations or lay writing.

https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/specificity

CSF lactate ³ 4 nmol/L has high sensitivity and specificity for bacterial meningitis following craniotomy.
0
0

In addition to these tissue specificity determinants a core set of basic pathogenicity factors will be generally required for plant colonization.
0
0

The sensitivity and specificity of clinical diagnostics during five decades.
0
0

By measuring genetic divergence between populations using molecular markers, I hope to relate this host specificity to the process of incipient speciation.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question though.

Comment: It does not answer the question directly; I agree.  It simply advises that "specificity" is probably a poor word choice for this application.  I do not think it makes sense to help someone shoehorn an inappropriate word in a specific context.